# How to pass ENUM variable as input for POSTGRESQL functions

Tags: postgresql, function, enums, input-parameters

I have a function in MySQL  which works fine:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `Accounts_Active`(IN_DeptName VARCHAR(255), IN_Src ENUM('TRAINING','ELZA'))
BEGIN
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But when converted to PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION Accounts_Active(IN_DeptName VARCHAR(255), IN_Src ENUM('TRAINING','ELZA'))
RETURNS void
AS
$$
BEGIN
      RAISE INFO '    ';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The following error occurs:

```
ERROR:  type enum does not exist
SQL state: 42704
```

Any guidance on how I can fix this error would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't define an enum on the fly. You need to have it already defined, then in your function you can say `in_src your_enum_type`

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. As 404 says, you need to define your enum before you can use it. Check out the PostgreSQL docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-enum.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an enum data type:

```
CREATE TYPE atype AS ENUM ('TRAINING', 'ELZA');
```

Then you can use it as function parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Accounts_Active(
   IN_DeptName text,
   IN_Src atype
) RETURNS void
...
```

When using enums, remember that you can add values to such a data type, but never again remove them. Often you will be better of using a string data type like `text`, but of course then you have to write code that checks the input for validity.